# Save values over end of program in application C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015

I want to save User-Settings with Visual Studio 2015, that don't reset after ending the application. For example you can choose the language and on the next startup of the application the settings are loaded. Is this possible without using external Files, StreamWriters and so on?

Comment: External files are most common way of doing this. Is there a specific reason you can't use them?

Comment: Use a `localdb` like SQLite or make use of JSON/XML to serialize and deserialize your class object and save to disk. You can also stay very simplistic and use a flat delimited file as a config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use application and user settings as described in [this MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx)

There is a distinction between app settings which are readonly at runtime, but valid for all users on the machine, and user settings, which can bei changed, but are only valid for the respective User.

You can create them via VS in the project properties -> settings. You use them in Code via

```
var x = Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting;
```

See the tutorial for further Details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already tried this, but I used it in a wrong way. Now everythink is working, thanks!